# What Intent to be used for Sirikit for ecommerce application

Tags: ios, sirikit

I am developing an E-Commerce application.
I want to integrate Sirikit with the app. 
Sample Instructions i want to give is in the following format

- Buy |Something| from |App Name|

I did everything but i am confused which Domain or Intent to choose. Would be great if someone could guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The only domain that seems suitable for your needs is the [Payment domain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/payments).

As its documentation states, the Payment domain can be used for bill payment to any vendors, so it seems like a good candidate for an eCommerce application. Specifically, you should be using the [INPayBillIntent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inpaybillintent) as this is the intent that should be used to facilitate a financial transaction between an individual (your user) and an entity (the seller of your eCommerce product).

Even this intent won't exactly match your use case, so most probably you won't be able to use the phrase *"Buy |Something| from |App Name|"*, but this is as close as you can get with the [currently available intent domains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit).

Comment: This actually works with Myntra. "Buy shirts with Myntra" works. I want something similar to that. Okay will try this and update

Comment: I used INPayBillIntent and had my own AppIntentVocabulary.plist, when i tried saying **Buy <something> from <Appname>** Siri kept telling  "<Appname> hasnt set that up with me yet.".

Comment: Can you see your app in the examples when clicking on the ? button in Siri?

Comment: What do you mean by "see your app in the examples"? are you talking about the suggestions?

Comment: I'm talking about the "Some things you can ask me" section